# Deleting the prometheus stateful set recreating itself

Tags: operator-keyword, prometheus, statefulset

I have deployed prometheus-operator using helm charts, I need to customize Prometheus stateful set but couldn't do it due to the nature of stateful set.
I have to delete the stateful by "kubectl delete sts prometheus-monitoring-prometheus-oper-Prometheus --cascade=false" but strangely it recreates the statefulset by itself.

Because of this issue, I couldn't able to update my stateful set.

Please help, how to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#configuration) helm chart docs if it allows you to do the change that you are looking for.
2. Use [helm upgrade](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/#helm-upgrade) to do any modification to the existing release not by manual edits.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is where Prometheus stateful set is controlled by the **prometheus/monitoring.coreos.com** CRD.

[image]

It has **ownerReference**, which says that the resource is controlled by another **resource/CRD/some-other-entity**.
In order to make any change/modifications/deletion you will need to go through the owner specified in **ownerReference**.

In this case the kind is Prometheus which has the following configuration;

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  annotations:
  labels:
    app: kube-prometheus-stack-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus-stack
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 37.3.0
    chart: kube-prometheus-stack-37.3.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: prometheus
  name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  namespace: default
spec:
  additionalScrapeConfigs:
    key: additional-scrape-configs.yaml
    name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-scrape-confg
  alerting:
    alertmanagers:
    - apiVersion: v2
      name: prometheus-kube-prometheus-alertmanager
      namespace: default
      pathPrefix: /
      port: web
  enableAdminAPI: false
  evaluationInterval: 30s
  externalLabels:
    cluster_name: test-cluster-01
    env: test
    kubernetes_cluster_name: test-cluster-01
    replica: test-cluster-01
  externalUrl: http://prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus.default:9090
  image: quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:v2.28.1
  listenLocal: false
  logFormat: logfmt
  logLevel: info
  paused: false
  podMonitorNamespaceSelector: {}
  podMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: prometheus
  portName: web
  probeNamespaceSelector: {}
  probeSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: prometheus
  remoteWrite:
  - url: http://prometheus01.domain.com:8990/api/v1/receive
  replicas: 1
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 2000m
      memory: 12288Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 7168Mi
  retention: 1d
  routePrefix: /
  ruleNamespaceSelector: {}
  ruleSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: prometheus
  scrapeInterval: 30s
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 2000
    runAsGroup: 2000
    runAsNonRoot: true
    runAsUser: 1000
  serviceAccountName: prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus
  serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector: {}
  serviceMonitorSelector:
    matchLabels:
      release: prometheus
  shards: 1
  version: v2.28.1
```

**kubectl get prometheus**

```
NAME                                    VERSION   REPLICAS   AGE
prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus   v2.28.1   1          141d
prometheus-prometheus-oper-prometheus   v2.28.1   1          141d
```

Hence to delete Prometheus statefulset you need to run

```
kubectl delete prometheus/prometheus-prometheus-oper-prometheus
```

If you want to modify resource limits, you will need to edit prometheus CRD which will then modify the statefulset.

Further Reading:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/owners-dependents/
- https://medium.com/@AbhijeetKasurde/kubernetes-ordered-cleanup-with-ownerreference-81adeaceb0c9